# Calculate length of text entered in RichTextBox c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have `RichTextBox` and I want to calculate the length of text entered in the `KeyDown` event. The problem is for characters in capital form I have to press `Shift` which is also getting calculated in the length. See the following code:

```
 private void rtfText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Modifiers != Keys.Shift)
        {
            var val = (char)e.KeyValue;
            string  _typed += val;                           
        }

}
```

For texts like **Win** with capital `W` the length of `_typed` is shown as `4` where as it should be `3`. How to solve this ? I wrote the above code to overcome this but now the length is shown as `2` instead of `3` because of suppressing `Shift`.

Comment: Why do you use `KeyDown`?

Comment: KeyDown is needed in the application logic

Comment: Yes tell us what forces you to stick to KeyDown?

Comment: As I type texts in the RichTextBox word suggestion( like VS intellisense) is shown near the word. Then on clicking on the suggestion box( on the choosen row) the entered text is replaced by the suggestion word

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `e.KeyCode` instead of `e.Modifiers`?  That way it is not incrementing your `val` if the key is `Keys.Shift`. e.Modifiers occurs when you hold shift down, so likely it is bypassing anything pressed while shift is held down.

Comment: e.KeyCode is also incrementing val

Comment: There's just no possible way to make it work with KeyDown.  Just Ctrl+V already completely ruins your count when it pastes a big chunk of text.  Just use the TextChanged event instead.  And use the TextLength property so you don't have to count yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code to this:

```
private void rtfText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl((char)e.KeyValue))
    {
        var val = (char)e.KeyValue;
        string  _typed += val;
    }
}
```

that way if a control key is pressed you won't count it or aggregate it to your string.
(PS: control keys are shift, ctrl ...)

see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/18zw7440(v=vs.95).aspx
it lists the control characters and explains what exactly the method `char.IsControl` does

**EDIT**: actually there is quite a lot of situations where it won't work. Of course you can try to handle every specific situation (such as `backspace`, `ctrl+V`...) but the simplest way would be to use the `TextLenght` property and the `TextChanged` event

Comment: And I suspect backspace also

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I thought this was a control key but no, you're right, backspace is also counted (just tested it)... Ok that's definitely not a good answer

Comment: @jeff you should go with JoeBrunsheon's answer, as you can see in all the comments my answer isn't very reliable, there's quite a lot of situations where it won't work

Comment: Someone should think about modifying the accepted answer to this question to be the more appropriate answer.

Comment: I can understand that, actually it served my purpose. All the other keys like backspace etc are handled in the application code logic, I was stuck with the Shift key only. This is the reason I accepted as the answer ( the answer to my problem )

Answer (score 1):

You should just get the TextLength property from the ritch text box directly:

```
var textLength = rtfText.TextLength
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted so much.  It's a heck of a lot better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually me too lol! I just posted the answer to deal with the concrete question asked, but I agree 100% that the way you proposed to do it is a lot better, counting on the `KeyDown` event isn't a safe way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes I agree, but the other keys like backspace etc are handled in the code logic. Thatz why I accepted it as the answer( to be frank the answer to my problem)

Comment: Now I'm curious. What part of TextLength doesn't work for you?